# Program not recognizing ArrayList Index

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

Below I've posted a snippet of my code that I am having some trouble with. Every time I run this program I get an error saying that

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Or in other words that the ArrayList isn't being created before I try and change values in it later on. What's really weird, however, is that when I replace realmHeight and realmWidth in the first for loop condition then I have no issues and the program works as intended. Could anyone shed some light as to why this is?

Btw, realmHeight and realmWidth take a String as a parameter for a filename, read from that file and spit out the correct max width and max height (in the printlns).

```
public class GuiMap extends Gui {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<GuiTile>> map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<GuiTile>>();
    private TileSet tileSet = new TileSet();
    private int tileSize;
    private String realm;

    public GuiMap(String name, String Realm) {
        super(name, 0, 0, 950, 600);
        realm = Realm;

        int realmHeight = getHeight() * 3;
        int realmWidth = getWidth()*3;

        try {
            realmHeight = countHeight(realm);
            realmWidth = countWidth(realm);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       
        System.out.println("realmHeight: " + realmHeight + " realmWidth: " + realmWidth);

        tileSize = tileSet.get("grasslands")[0].getWidth();

        //make the map arrayList fill the entire screen
        int nameNum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < realmHeight; i++) {
            ArrayList<GuiTile> temporary = new ArrayList<GuiTile>();
            for (int j = 0; j < realmWidth; j++) {
                temporary.add(new GuiTile("Tile" + nameNum, j*tileSize, i*tileSize, tileSize, tileSet.get("grasslands")));
                nameNum++;
            }
            map.add(temporary);
        }

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(realm));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't find file to generate map from");
        }

        String currentLine = null;

        try {
            int i = 0;

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                char[] line = currentLine.toCharArray();
                ArrayList<GuiTile> temp = new ArrayList<GuiTile>();
                for (int j = 0; j < currentLine.length(); j++) {

                    switch (line[j]) {

                        case '0': map.get(i).get(j).tileValue = 0; break;
                        case '1': map.get(i).get(j).tileValue = 1; break;
                        case '2': map.get(i).get(j).tileValue = 2; break;
                        case '3': map.get(i).get(j).tileValue = 3; break;

                        default: map.get(i).get(j).tileValue = 0; break;
                    }
                }
                map.add(temp);
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't read from file. Please check map file");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.gui.GuiMap.<init>(GuiMap.java:81)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.Game.<init>(Game.java:27)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.gui.GuiLogin.login(GuiLogin.java:76)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.gui.GuiLogin.access$0(GuiLogin.java:73)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.gui.GuiLogin$1.run(GuiLogin.java:36)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.gui.GuiButton.onClicked(GuiButton.java:30)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.gui.Gui$1.run(Gui.java:31)
    at gg.mc.OneQuest.engine.Mouse$1.mouseClicked(Mouse.java:26)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6507)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Have you debugged into it? What are `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` returning?

Comment: oh, getHeight and getWidth return 650 and 900 respectively. They are the functions that return the bounding box dimensions of the window. Furthermore, the realmHeight and realmWidth functions print 45 and 36 respectively (in the println).

Comment: Why do you always add an empty list in your second loop? (`map.add(temp)`). That looks pointless to me.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace for us?

Comment: You are assigning variables realmHeight and realmWidth while declaring then and immediately after that in try catch you are reassigning them. Any reason for this? Are you getting valid object at tileSet.get("grasslands")[0]? Please share stack trace.

Comment: I am assigning the variables again because I assign an arbitrary one first for safety and then an actual one. In case the actual fails I can rely on the arbitrary one. I will provide stack trace in the morning, in bed atm.

Comment: Jon skeet, how are you saying that the list is empty? I think that is what is happening, but I'm pretty sure that the list fills ... Also The purpose is to fill the arraylist of arraylists.

Comment: Show us the line where something is added to temp.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, something gets added to temp here: `temporary.add(new GuiTile("Tile" + nameNum, j*tileSize, i*tileSize, tileSize, tileSet.get("grasslands")));`

Comment: Second loop, the one with the switch statement. That should be the `temp` Jon Skeet is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Error resolved:

It turns out that I needed to add a `+1` to the for loop where I'm originally creating. I'm not quite sure why my program was saying that it was at index 0 that I wasn't able to do it, though I suppose it could be at the last row of the ArrayList which is not declared. So, I fixed the error by making the for loop that adds the tiles use `<=` instead of `<`.

Thanks for the help guys.